# What does Ruby logger with shift_age 'w' do?

Tags: ruby, logging

What does a Ruby logger that looks like this do?

```
logger = Logger.new('foo.log', 'w')
```

The closest thing I can find on the docs is

```
logger = Logger.new('foo.log', 'weekly')
```

Or perhaps write only?

```
file = File.open('foo.log', File::WRONLY | File::APPEND)
```

I'd assume it means weekly?

Comment: Where did you encounter this code?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - The `'w'` itself means nothing when creating a new `Logger` object. But `'weekly'` is a viable argument.

I am not sure where you got your initial example from. However, based on the docs, the second (optional) argument of [`Logger::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-c-new) is `shift_age`:

> Number of old log files to keep, **or** frequency of rotation (`daily`, `weekly` or `monthly`).

Any option other than those above will still create a successful log object. (Tested in 1.9.3)

```
[1] pry(main)> logger = Logger.new('foo.log', 'nothing')
=> #<Logger:0x00000001023590
 @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00000001023540 @datetime_format=nil>,
 @formatter=nil,
 @level=0,
 @logdev=
  #<Logger::LogDevice:0x000000010234a0
   @dev=#<File:foo.log>,
   @filename="foo.log",
   @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x00000001023450 @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x00000001023388>, @mon_owner=nil>,
   @shift_age="nothing",
   @shift_size=1048576>,
 @progname=nil>
```

Knowing this, the `'w'` itself does not mean write-only when creating a new logger. Just because a logger may write to a file, the logger and file are still two different objects.

[More information on HOW TO create a logger](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-How+to+create+a+logger)